# Beta regression with categorical predictor variable

Tags: regression, beta-regression

Is it ok to run a beta regression with proportion data (as the y variable) and **categorical predictor variables**? i.e., I know the R etc. will often do the conversion for you, but I just want to make sure the results are still ok/valid?

All of the documentation that I can find says continuous predictor variables.

Comment: Yes, as long as your software handles it well.  The `betareg` package in R is fine with this.

Answer (score 2):

Beta regression is based on a linear predictor for the expectation of a beta-distributed response variable, by default with a logit-link: $\mathrm{logit}(\mu_i) = x_i^\top \beta$. Often, a second linear predictor is added for the precision parameter $\log(\phi_i) = z_i^\top \gamma$. Thus, all the usual strategies to build a linear predictor from a set of originally measured variables can be applied, e.g., polynomials, splines, interactions, etc. And for categorical variables the usual way to do this is via contrasts, see e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352617/how-and-why-do-you-use-contrasts

In R `model.matrix()` is used internally to set up the regressor matrix using `contrasts()`. This is employed in `lm()`, `glm()`, and also in `betareg()` (among many many other packages). Many practitioners do not change the default contrasts but two examples in `vignette("betareg", package = "betareg")` actually do. In `GasolineYield` the `batch` uses the default treatment contrasts but with batch 10 (rather than 1) as the reference category. And in `ReadingSkills` the `dyslexia` variable uses sum contrasts for an effect coding. (See also [How to do regression with effect coding instead of dummy coding in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52132/how-to-do-regression-with-effect-coding-instead-of-dummy-coding-in-r))